# nsis adds empty folders to the installer

Tags: wildcard, nsis

The `File` below:

```
; Install common files
SetOutPath "${GameDir}\Mopy"
File /r /x "*.bat" /x "*.py*" /x "w9xpopen.exe" /x "Wrye Bash.exe" "Mopy\*.*"
```

filters out some directories that contain python files but still those directories are created (although empty, or containing empty subdirectories) when I run the installer. Those folders need to be included to the installer (if I get the terminology correct at "compile time") cause the installer has an option to install the python version of the program. I can't come up with a way to not add these empty folders. Is there some wildcard I could use to that purpose or should I go and remove the files on installation (using RMDir ?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have two options and one is indeed `RMDir` if you are OK with it possibly removing empty folders that the user created.

The other option is to not use `File /r ...` and instead use `!system` to execute something like a batch file that generates a text file with individual `File` instructions that you can `!include`. It would look something like this:

```
!tempfile files
!system '"mygeneratefilelist.bat" "${files}"'
!include "${files}"
!delfile "${files}"
```

and the batch file would use `FOR` and/or `DIR` to list and `ECHO` the `File` commands to `%1`...

Comment: Oh thanks - I'd go with RMDirs but really is this as it looks or is something I am missing here ? That is it adds the folders even if empty ? And there is no way to tell it not to ? nsis noob here...

Comment: I think you can exclude directories as well with /x but that is about it.

Comment: Hmmm - let me give that a whirl

Comment: Yep `/x "Mopy\bash\bosh\*.*"` does it for me - great I hated the RMDir, lest the User had anything valuable in there, I would have to warn and whatnot - plus it was a hack, what I really wanted was excluding those dirs. Would ``/x "Mopy\bash\bosh"` make any difference ?

Comment: RMDir only removes empty directories so it is pretty safe, RMDir /r on the other hand will delete a whole directory tree. I don't remember the exact details of how /x works so you would just have to try it.

Comment: Thanks - I intended to use `/r` - actually I was wrong above `/x "Mopy\bash\bosh\*.*"` did not do it - neither did `/x "Mopy\bash\bosh"` - what worked was `/x "bosh"` - but that would match anything named "bosh" (see note at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/File ) - would be nice to be able to specify we want directory matches only